# useing 2 tables mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a web site that has a movie list. What I am looking to do is make it so the user can check of and rate the movies that they have seen. I have 2 different tables one for the users and one for the movies. This is my first attempt to have 2 tables link and as such I am not sure what the starting point on something like this. I want to use the movie ID as the identifier in the user profile. But I cant think of a good way to put that into the user database neatly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make one table Users:

- UserID
- Username
- Date of birth, ...

One table Movies:

- MovieID
- Moviename
- Productionyear, ...

And a table to link them:

- LinkID
- UserREF (here you put the userID of the user)
- MovieREF (here you put the MovieID of the movie)
- Rating
- Datetime, ...

Now, you can work with these tables just like this, but you can do a little extra to ensure your data stays valid: if you add a constraint on UserREF and MovieREF, there can't be lines in the Link-table without a corresponding user or movie.

Comment: By doing it this way then you would have a new line each time someone checked a movie off?

Comment: Yes. That is the way it is done in a RDBMS.

Comment: Cool thanks. I'll be working on that tonight

Comment: No need for the LinkID field. Better to just create primary key on UserREF and MovieREF as presumably it will need a unique key on these two fields anyway.

Comment: You said it. Presumably. I always give an autoincrement primary key to my tables, even my link tables. Later you'll want to refer to the link (example: reaction on a review?) and you'll have to start using the two fields to react too. Your key then becomes three fields. Then someone reacts to that reaction... etc.

Answer (score 1):

you need a third table. for example

```
user_movie_rating: user_id, movie_id, rating
```

to read the rating for a movie do like

```
SELECT SUM(rating) / COUNT(user_id) FROM user_movie_rating WHERE movie_id = x
```

Comment: What''s wrong with `AVG(rating)` tout court?